# Server Error Model: Stock Move (stock.move), Field: Product (product_id)

Tags: bundle, inventory, odoo-12

I downloaded this app "Odoo Product Pack (Bundle) or Combo Products"
for the odoo store but after creating the Bundle when I try to use it in Quotations
this "Server Error" shows

The operation cannot be completed:

- Create/update: a mandatory field is not set.
- Delete: another model requires the record being deleted. If possible, archive it instead.

Model: Stock Move (stock.move), Field: Product (product_id)

The error happens when I try to confirm

Comment: Check if you setup the product pack correctly. This error always come when you miss to update a required field value. Product id on stock.move is required and it is missing therefore you are getting this error message.

Answer (score -1):

This error comes when you try to delete product which is associated with some stock move. So please delete stock moves of the product first and then delete products